# Two Domains on one website?

Tags: ssl, iis-6, dns

I'm investigating a little problem for my employer. My company runs a website under an SSL certificate for the domain www.domainone.net.nz (Yes, New Zealand)

However, there's been a high-level marketing decision to change our primary domain to www.domaintwo.co.nz.

So, easy, right? Buy a new SSL cert for www.domaintwo.co.nz and get it running on IIS. Easy.

However, we have a few WebServices published that need to be accessed over HTTPS - there's some systems in place out in the wild that are using https://www.domainone.net.nz/

I would like to run BOTH certs at the same time, and give our partners and clients that are using these WebServices a set timeframe (six months, say) to roll over to the new domain, before revoking the www.domainone.net.nz cert.

This is a bit fiddly to search for - I keep getting explanations of wildcard SSL domains, which wouldn't help in this particular case, as the central domain name has changed.

Is this possible under IIS? My asp.dll shows version 6.0.3790.4195

Comment: Okay, thanks guys,

Did a bit more digging, and I've changed my mind. Getting additional IP's is gonna be too much work, and our partner base is too small right now to warrant a multi-domain cert. Also, managing two IP's is a bit of an overkill.

We're going to get a new, basic SSL for www.domaintwo.co.nz - this will override the www.domainone.net.nz on our server. We'll just have to be careful about communicating this very carefully and with much time to spare to the partners using our WebServices.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, if you have separate IP addresses for both sites, simply create two sites, one with each SSL certificate and point the directories for both sites to the same place.

But with a single website, no it's not possible

Comment: So, if site one uses www.xxx.yyy.zzz:443 for SSL, and site two uses www.xxx.yyy.zzz:444, it won't work? The IPs have to be totally different? I have two sites in IIS pointing to the same directory, and each has an SSL cert for its domain, but requests to the new domain still try to use the old domain's cert, so I get an error.

Comment: You can use different ports yes, however that's pretty undiscoverable.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do this as long as you have two different IP's one for each of the SSL Certs, you may have to set up two sites that point to the same location to get it working properly, but im not sure.